# SKReferenceNode's SKPhysicsBody Off Center and Invisible

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am working on a game, and I am using an alpha mask to create an SKPhysicsBody for the basket + catcher. The SKView has showPhysics set to true.

[image: Broken]

I can't figure out what in the world the disc is hitting. There is no physics field there. When I recreate the reference node with SKSpriteNodes this works flawlessly. I would like to use a reference node though because it would make it easier to make lots of these quickly. Here is where I set up the reference node:

[image: Reference Node]

Here is where I create the scene itself:

[image: Scene]

I have zero idea at this point what is happening. Clearly there is an error with showing the physics as well, because there is no blue outline there.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of it's bit categories and collision categories to see if it still occurs?

Comment: @JozemiteApps Just tested that. It no longer hits the invisible physics. (Of course it doesn't hit where they are supposed to be either.

Comment: I would try to delete the scene and create a new one. I've always had bugs with scenes so I don't ever create them except with code. Every time I've dealt with scenes, sometimes all the objects I placed disappear randomly and then I would have to start all over again.

Comment: @JozemiteApps It happens with all of the scenes I have sadly... I would really like to use the scene editor simply because there are going to be a lot of scenes. It would be an absolute pain to do them all programmatically.

Comment: how large is your basket scene size?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia 1575 x 760. I use a camera node to scroll around.

Comment: use `view.showPhysics = true` to see what it is hitting

Comment: @Knight0fDragon showPhysics is set to true already. It is part of the problem.

Comment: Can you show contactAnode and contactBnode Log in contact func?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia It is saying that it is hitting the reference node. I have a feeling this may be an issue with the camera somehow.

Comment: So if you set the the basket.sks size = basketNode works?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia It seems to have changed it a little, but the problem still persists. Also, the basket reference node is made up of two pieces. Not sure if that makes a difference.